# AJAX PHP Is Not Working in Node.js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, node.js, ajax

### The Problem:

When I put a PHP file link in the browser, it works perfectly fine and updates my database as expected.

When I call it with ajax from node.js, it echoes the success message but the DB does not update.

The Session variables are undefined, so when I changed them to real numbers the code still did not work. What is going wrong?

---

### My PHP Code:

**subtract5.php:**

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://cashballz.net:3000', false);
include 'mysql.php'; 
session_start(); 

$cash_amount = $_SESSION['cash_amount'];
$userid = $_SESSION['id'];
$_SESSION['cash_amount'] -= 0.05;

$mysql = new Mysql(); 

$result = $mysql->setCashAmount($cash_amount,$userid); 
if($result) 
{ 
echo $cash_amount; 
} 
else 
{ 
session_start(); 
session_unset(); 
session_destroy(); 
}
?>
```

**mysql.php:**

```
<?php
class Mysql 
{ 
protected $dsn; 
protected $username; 
protected $password; 
public $db; 


function __construct() 
{ 
//change this to your info (myDBname, myName, myPass) 
$this->dns= 'mysql:dbname=cashball_accounts;host=localhost;charset=utf8'; 
$this->username= 'myUser'; 
$this->password= 'myPass'; 
$this->db = new PDO($this->dns, $this->username, $this->password); 
} 


public function setCashAmount($cash_amount, $id) 
{ 
$sql = "UPDATE users SET cash_amount = :cash_amount - 0.05 WHERE id = :id"; 
$stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql); 
$stmt->bindParam(':cash_amount', $cash_amount, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$result = $stmt->execute(); 
return $result; 
} 

} 
?>
```

**My node.js (app.js) AJAX:**

```
//cut 5 cents from account - php function
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'http://cashballz.net/game/5game/subtract5.php',
        data: {}, 
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
```

---

**Recap:**

- PHP File works from site.com with the same AJAX code, and by putting its link in the browser.
- PHP File is executed from node, but does not update the DB
- PHP File has undefined $_SESSION variables but when replaced, the DB still does not update

---

**Possible solutions:**

- Is there extra code i can put in AJAX to tell it to "pipe" the call to site.com to call the file instead of calling it straight from node?

---

**Extra Info:**

- No errors in error logs or console
- I need to use AJAX to input data into the file later on
- Solution must be secure

---

***Thanks for the help!***

Comment: You do not seem to be *`POST`* ing any data

Comment: Check the AJAX Code, i don't need to POST

Comment: Why **in the name of all that is unholy** are you doing a jQuery ajax call from a nodejs app? Node is not a browser. Node has it's own network functions.

Comment: "Solution must be secure"? There is nothing secure about this url `http://cashballz.net/game/5game/subtract5.php`

Comment: Where are you adding the sessions to the DB? Are sure the session you expect via ajax is in your DB?

Comment: Have a look at the [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) library for node.js. It is not a good idea to use jQuery server-side

Comment: @RedJandal Alright i'll test it out, do i just request the php file's link?

Comment: @MrGlass The php file works, which means it's not the file's fault.

Comment: @gforce301 Terrible response, you criticize without an explanation

Comment: The php doesn't work fine. You need to go read up and understand how php sessions actually work. I gave you 2 explanations. 1) **Node has it's own network functions** You should use them. Ajax is for browsers. 2) If you think that `http` is secure then I really can't help you at all. `https` is the secure version.

Comment: @Patrick, I'm not implying that it's the "file's fault". I'm saying we cannot see where the sessions are getting added to the DB so we can't tell if the session is actually in the DB, which would explain why your query is not finding it to decrement the value.

Comment: It's not working because this line: `$userid = $_SESSION['id'];` that id in the session is null. It's null because calling that script with an ajax call from nodejs, php is unable to initiate the same session (no cookies and all that, see my previous comment about actually learning how php sessions work) so php starts a new session and that id is null in the new session. So your query in your `setCashAmount` function never matches a user so nothing gets updated. Like I said, The php doesn't work fine. At least not in the way you are trying to do this.

Comment: @Patrick yes you can create a request to the php url, but as per the comment by gforce301, you have other issues in your PHP that needs to be addressed. Unless you make the call from the same browser the php session is initiated your code will not work. Node.js is server-side and will create it's own session and will not be aware of the user session.

Comment: @gforce301 In my post I explained that i replaced all SESSION values with numbers and the database still did not update. I set user id to my user's id and cash amount to my user's cash amount and the DB did not update.

Comment: @gforce301 I also just bought SSL, i'm activating it soon

Comment: @RedJandal So you're saying i need to call it from site.com? i tried changing the variables to real values instead of session values and the PHP still didn't work. I need to call the file from site.com:3000, and that's the problem. Sorry if i just didn't understand your response.

Comment: @Patrick, you should re-evaluate the way you're building whatever you're building... This is not a safe way, for sure. You have a php file on a server that is called by a node.js app via jQuery ajax call... SSL won't help making the whole thing safer. Complaining with others because they tell you the truth won't help you either. What you should do is some good RTFM :)

Comment: @Alberto You told me what I did wrong by restating what others said, and did not even say how to fix them. There's a reason why this site exists and its to get advice and answers, and you supplied none of that. Thanks. P.S. I'm looking for answers not fights.